# Percentage of income problem

Tags: percentages

A family paid 12 percent of its annual after-tax income on food last year. This amount was equal to 10 percent of its annual before-tax income last year. Which of the following is closest to the percent of the family's annual before-tax income that was paid for taxes last year?

A. 8%
B. 12%
C. 17%
D. 20%
E. 25%

My thoughts are set the after-tax income as x and before-tax income as y, then 0.12x = 0.10y, meaning y = 1.2x. And here is where I got stuck, please help me with this problem.

Comment: HINT: $y-x=t$ where $t$ represents tax paid, you want to calculate $$\frac tx$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a$ be the after-tax income. Then

$$\frac{12}{100}a$$

is the after-tax income spent on food.

Let $b$ be the before-tax income. Then

$$\frac{10}{100}b=\frac{12}{100}a.$$

You need to find

$$1-\frac{a}{b}.$$